# Alternative language to do Cocoa programming

Tags: objective-c

I'm a C++, Java developer and I want to program for Mac in something "nicer" than Objective-C.

I know Java Swing can mimic the MacOS X UI, but a Java Swing program is not a Cocoa first citizen. Also I know that I can use Qt in C++ or Jambi in Java to use the Qt toolkit that performs Cocoa calls but, though that is not a bad idea, it adds an abstraction layer in all the thing.

So, is there something like "Vala" for GTK+ or some Java bindings or some stuff to do Cocoa programming with no need of all the Objective-C thing?

[DISCLAIMER: "nicer" is just my appreciation, no trolling there]

Comment: Please realize - if you use a non-Objective-C binding, you are really just going to make more work for yourself as a beginner.  It will not get you out of understanding ObjC, it will just add a layer of indirection.  ObjC is an easy language, lots of people like it, just go with it. After you know what you're doing you can consider a language binding.

Comment: I'd ask why? What is your motivation for doing this? You certainly won't save any time, or learn more.

Comment: doing Cocoa without Obj-C?  mind as well ask for a house with no doors.  you can also code in C++, it'll compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed an inflammatory question.

There are bindings for Ruby and Python, if those fit your bill.

http://developer.apple.com/leopard/overview/apptech.html

Objective-C isn't all that un-nice and not all that dissimilar to Java in several ways, really, if you take some time to learn it.

Comment: Have a look here as well: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: The purpose of those bridges is to allow Cocoa apps to use Ruby or Python libraries.  DO NOT use them as a way to avoid learning Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

[MacRuby + HotCocoa](http://macruby.org/) lets you do it all in Ruby, and in a Rubyesque way - it looks more natural than a foreign binding might suggest.

Comment: MacRuby is actually implemented in the Objective-C runtime. It is the only alternative language that has a claim to being as native as Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

Give [Monobjc](http://www.monobjc.net/) a shot. It's been great to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in .NET programming, you can use the Mono framework to program in pretty much any environment, including iPhone:
http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page